# What do the results of tuning β1, β2 in ADAM imply about the gradients or the data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization

For example:

If I have a simple 3-layer neural network that demonstrates better performance on the test set when the value of β2 is .95 when compared to the default .999 over several trials of cross-validation, is there any assumption that we can make about properties of the data or gradients?

Is there any literature on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot make assumptions on the data because of this. If you want literature on the matter I would suggest reading the original paper by [Kingma](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980). You should see the adam method solely as an optimizer. The optimizer often works better in certain classes of data. This does however not imply the converse: so tuning parameters does not necessarily mean that the data has certain characteristics.